# С# WPF(MVVM) Как взаимодействовать с DependencyProperty из ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Только недавно начал постигать паттерн MVVM, и столкнулся со следующим вопросом. Как правильно получить доступ к `DependencyProperty` из `ViewModel`. В классическом подходе с этим никаких проблем нет ибо все находится в `code-behind`, а вот MVVM подходе вообще не понятно что с этим делать. Например мы хотим собрать свой `FilePicker` у которого будет свойство `FileName` к которому в будущем можно будет привязаться.

### View

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="Demo.FilePicker"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:localControls="clr-namespace:Demo.Controls"
    x:Name="filePickerControl">

    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <localControls:FilePickerViewModel />
    </UserControl.DataContext>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBox
            x:Name="fileNameTextBox"
            Grid.Column="0"
            IsReadOnly="True"
            Text="{Binding ElementName=filePickerControl, Path=FileName}" />
        <Button
            x:Name="browseFileButton"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Command="{Binding Path=BrowseCommand}"
            Content="Browse…" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

### View code-behind

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace Demo.Controls
{
    public partial class FilePicker : UserControl
    {
        public string FileName
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(FileNameProperty); }
            set { SetValue(FileNameProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty FileNameProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("FileName", typeof(string), typeof(FilePicker), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata() { BindsTwoWayByDefault = true });

        public FilePicker()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

### ViewModel

```cs
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.Windows;

namespace Demo.Controls
{
    class FilePickerViewModel : BindableBase
    {
        private string _fileName;
        public string FileName
        {
            get { return _fileName; }
            set 
            { 
                _fileName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private DelegateCommand _browseCommand;
        public DelegateCommand BrowseCommand =>
            _browseCommand ?? (_browseCommand = new DelegateCommand(ExecuteBrowseCommand));

        public FilePickerViewModel()
        {

        }

        void ExecuteBrowseCommand()
        {
            var openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();

            if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
                FileName = openFileDialog.FileName;
            else
                FileName = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Как связать `FileName` из `View` и `FileName` из `ViewModel` в режиме `TwoWay`. Или как сразу получить доступ к свойству зависимости из ViewModel.

P.S.
Я знаю что можно объявить `DependencyProperty` в `ViewModel`, но мне кажется что размазывать `View` по `ViewModel`, которая вообще о `View` знать не должна, это не лучшая идея.

Comment: `<FilePicker FileName = "{Binding FileName}" />`....

Comment: EvgeniyZ, вы немного не поняли, мне нужно связать свойство из ```FilePickerViewModel``` и свойство зависимости из ```FilePicker```, как внутреннюю реализацию этого контрола. Для того чтобы в будущем в разметке окна использовать приведенный вами код)
То есть метод из ```ViewModel``` должен внести значение в свойство зависимости View которой эта  ```ViewModel``` принадлежит.

Comment: Если вы пишете контрол, то причем тут VM? У контрола не должно быть VM внутри

Comment: Андрей, в данный момент я так и реализовал свой контрол (без vm). Но правильно ли смешение подходов в одном проекте? Чем принципиально отличается работа с Window от работы с UserControl? Ведь они оба могут содержать много сложной логики. Разве mvvm придуман не для ее отделения от View.

Comment: MVVM придуман для отделения логики представления от другой логики. Всё что происходит внутри контрола — это всё логика представления (View) и никаким моделям до нее нет дела. PS: обращайтесь через @, иначе я не получаю уведомлений о комментарии мне адресованном.

Comment: @АндрейNOP я понял, спасибо за разъяснение.